# how to get scope property in link function to be read by ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The directive that I am working on has everything inside of the link function.  I have some information that I need to hide with an ng-if  like so ...

```
<div class="seatmap-error-message" ng-if="travelingWithPassenger.Type != 'Adult'">
```

I am getting the property from the a custom directive with an isolated scope that looks like so

```
link: function ($scope) {

  $scope.travelingWithPassenger = $scope.svc.passengers.filter(function (obj) {
       return obj.Type === 'Adult'
    })[0];
```

I know that the original developer is not using best practices with angular but refactoring that code is a bit down the line for me.

I tried to create a custom filter like so

```
module.filter('unaccompaniedMinor', function (haVerticalSeatmapService) {
        return function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            var travelingWithAdult = haVerticalSeatmapService.passengers;
        }
    });
```

And add this inside of the ng-if but that wasn't hitting.

Looking for some direction anything helps at this point.

Comment: what is the problem in your first process and how used second process?

Comment: first process the value worked out great but I am seeing the template loaded before my debugger runs through the link function.